# java and BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i would like to check if a variable is a bigDecimal, is there a method for that?

my code:

```
private KeystrokeTextField myRate;

// how can i check if myRate.getText() is a bigdecimal?
BifDecimal test = myRate.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `BigDecimal` (meaning, call the `BigDecimal` constructor) using that text. Wrap that call inside a `try/catch`.